# Что делать если вылезает ошибка EOL while scanning string literal, когда я хочу запустить код guess

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Эта игра по угадыванию чисел.
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Привет! Как тебя зовут?')
myName = input()

print('Будешь играть в "Угадай число"?')
answer = input()

number = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Что ж, давай начнём! Я загадал число от 1 до 20')

for guessesTaken in range(6):
    print('Попробуй угадать.') # Четыре пробелов перед именем функции print
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)

    if guess < number:
        print('Твоё число слишком маленькое.') # Восемь пробелов перед именем функции print

    if guess > number:
        print('Твоё число слишком большое.')

    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken + 1)
    print('Отлично, ' + myName + '! ы справился за ' + guessesTaken + ' попытки!)

if guess != number:
    number= str(number)
    print('Увы. Я загадал число ' + number + '.')`# Эта игра по угадыванию чисел.
import random

guessesTaken = 0

print('Привет! Как тебя зовут?')
myName = input()

print('Будешь играть в "Угадай число"?')
answer = input()

number = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Что ж, давай начнём! Я загадал число от 1 до 20')

for guessesTaken in range(6):
    print('Попробуй угадать.') # Четыре пробелов перед именем функции print
    guess = input()
    guess = int(guess)

    if guess < number:
        print('Твоё число слишком маленькое.') # Восемь пробелов перед именем функции print

    if guess > number:
        print('Твоё число слишком большое.')

    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
    guessesTaken = str(guessesTaken + 1)
    print('Отлично, ' + myName + '! ы справился за ' + guessesTaken + ' попытки!)

if guess != number:
    number= str(number)
    print('Увы. Я загадал число ' + number + '.')
```

доброго времени суток. Я новичок. У меня вылезает ошибка EOL while scanning string literal и я не знаю как её исправить. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: не закрыта последняя кавычка в строчке print('Отлично, ' + myName + '! ы справился за ' + guessesTaken + ' попытки!) Каждая IDE, даже IDLE указывает на это красным цветом. Даже здесь на сайте подсветка кода на это указывает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже вы забыли поставить кавычки в этой строке:

```
print('Отлично, ' + myName + '! ы справился за ' + guessesTaken + ' попытки!')
```

Comment: Спасибо вам, теперь всё работает